# Javascript need regex to add to the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to add a variable to the end of my href using regex and jquery. This is what i have so far:

```
$('#survey-click1').click(function(event) {
      playerPause();
      $("a[href^=http://d.surveysonline.com/]")
          .each(function()
      {
        this.href = [regex goes here];
      });
      return false;
});
```

I'm simply trying to add a variable at the end of the url i clicked on to attach whether or not the video i just watched had a preroll or not. This could be done easily by attaching this to the end of my url code `[&preroll="+Kdp3State.preroll+"]`. How do i detect the end of the href string to attach this to to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is actually what you want to append to your URL, this should work:

```
$("a[href^=http://d.surveysonline.com/]").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href', '&preroll='+Kdp3State.preroll);
});
```

Apart from the fact that you use a CSS selector that is somewhat similiar to a regex, this question seems be unrelated to the subject.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a regexp, just do:

```
this.href += 'string_to_be_appended';
```

e.g.

```
this.href += '&preroll=' + encodeURIComponent(Kdp3State.preroll);
```

Note the use of `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that any special characters (+, %, etc) in the resulting URI are correctly encoded.

Comment: Judging from his code, he is using jQuery. `this.href` would be invalid in that case. Instead, use `this.attr('href')`

Comment: actually, it looks like I was right.  `$(selector).each()` supplies the underlying elements in `this`, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Oh, nice :) I didn't actually know that. We learn something new every day, I guess. (*still seems pretty odd though*)

Comment: that's why I hang around here - sometimes you learn a lot from ones own incorrect answers :)

Comment: FWIW, from http://api.jquery.com/each/ - "the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element"

Answer (score 0):

```
this.href += "&preroll=" + Kdp3State.preroll
```

or

```
this.href = this.href.replace(/&preroll=[^&]+/g, "") + "&preroll=" + Kdp3State.preroll;
```

?